# How to correctly include requirejs and react & JSX in gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, requirejs, jsx

I am writing a project which was generated with [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp). This package generates a `gulp` based project.

I chose to write my application with `react` including `JSX` files (with `.jsx` files extensions). Moreover, I preferred to use the ES6 syntax with the `import ____ from '____'` statements.

I am trying to write a gulp task which will handle the react files with the `.jsx` extension, something like this:

```
gulp.task('react-scripts', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.jsx')

        // run some pipes with the files

        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

This pipes should deal with the `ES6` syntax, and include plugins of `react` and `requirejs` (because I am using the `import` statement).

I read about packages like `gulp-requirejs` and `gulp-jsx`, but they are blacklisted as you can see [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json).

There is an efficient way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @KarlTaylor I have. My problem is that the babel converts the imports to `require` statements, and the browser doesn't recognize it. This is why I should use something like `requirejs`.

Comment: try looking into coupling it with http://browserify.org/

Comment: Why not https://webpack.github.io/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently use browserify/Babelify with my React setup.

```
const browserify = require('browserify')
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer')
const notify = require('gulp-notify')

gulp.task('js', () => {
  return browserify('src/js/main.js', { debug: true })
    .transform('babelify', {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
    })
    .bundle().on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.stack)
        return 'error in JS'
      }
    }))
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dir))
    .pipe(notify('Javascript Finished Compiling'))
})
```

And my `main.js` would include all my imports and my react render.